# Cannot Install Ubuntu - no option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside my Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 operating systems.

When I boot up from the live CD, it doesn't give me an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

I tried clicking on something else too -- it just showed my whole disk as one unallocated partition.

I don't think I have 4 primary partitions either. I once converted them to logical partitions too!

Can someone help me to install Ubuntu?

I have a 1TB hard disk and I have only used around 200 GB for both of the operating systems! I have lots of space left. What do I do now?

[image]

Comment: add the output to your question: run `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` I'm assuming you have the GPT-disk

Comment: @JohnnyD - you can get most of the info from the image... **harikrishnan**, there are likely two main reasons for this - you already have a dual boot of Windows 7 & 8 - and there is no space on the disk for Ubuntu to be installed on.

Comment: I hav 1tb hard disk....  i have only used around 200 Gb for bth the Os! I have lots of space left.... Wat do i do now?

Comment: @Wilf you are right but there's always something like MultiOS which  is more than 2 OS https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiOSBoot

Comment: read that article probably it'll give you a clue

Comment: The above screenshot sadly doesn't say you have loads of space left - if you shrink the some of the Windows data partitions *(try to avoid any with Windows bootloaders - probably the D or E drive is the one you need to shrink)* - you should have enough space to install Ubuntu on - See [this bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiOSBoot#Changing_Windows_partition_sizes) of johnnyD's article. Backup any important data first. JohnnyD, I do know more than 2 OS can be on a drive, by the way :D

Comment: I used always triple boot before with linux ,windows 8 and 7.....now should i shrink the drive where i have not install windows or the drive where i hav?

Comment: Should i hav a unallocated space aftr shrinnk or should i make it to a new partition.....if  so wat kinda partition

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost certainly caused by leftover GPT data on an MBR disk. You can correct this problem by running [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) (part of the Ubuntu `gdisk` package) on the disk. Once you've done that, you should be able to resize partitions to make it all work.

Also, be sure to [disable the Windows 8 Fast Startup feature.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) This feature is incompatible with a dual- (much less a triple-)boot configuration.

Comment: What do i do with fixparts